Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()" because the return value of "java.lang.Exception.getCause()" is null
Message in subject is topmost in stacktrace.
The rest of Liquibase related stack looks as the following.
[liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()" because the return value of "java.lang.Exception.getCause()" is null,   
at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:253),   
at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$0(Liquibase.java:245),   
at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:186),   
at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:195),   
at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:185),   
at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:164),   
at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1419),  
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:234),  
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:212),  
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:194),  
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179),  

And that's all info I have.
I understand it is almost nothing. Nevertheless maybe someone could make some tip or suggestion.
What could be the reason for this error?
Liquibase 4.26.0
